# jquery css cannot set the height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small issue in my webpage. this issue is coming up only in firefox. The issue is: there is a very big gap between footer and the above content, that height is set by some other js, but i am trying to set the height by this:

```
    <style>
     .importantRule { height: 5320px !important; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#nimble_portfolio_grid_1').addClass('importantRule');  
     });
    </script>
```

this is the link to my page: http://www.blanke-kreation.de/neu/referenzen/ as you see, the bottom distance to footer is very large. why my jquery is not setting the height?

please help to find the bug

thanks a lot

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, yeah, it is 20201 something like that

Comment: Wouldn't it be wiser to set the `height` to `auto` at this point? 5000 seems abusive.

Comment: Why are you nesting so many divs? BTW, IDs must be unique on context page, your HTML is invalid

Comment: @roasted, it is a plugin,

Comment: You have many DIVs with same id "nimble-portfolio-maker-shortcode". Which plugin creates so wrong HTML?

Comment: @roasted, this page is of my colleague, she says, this is wordpress.

Comment: You have 22 nested DIVs with same ID, you should really fix that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something on your page is conflicting with jQuery.  Using `$` is the problem in this case.

Try this instead...

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        $('#nimble_portfolio_grid_1').addClass('importantRule');  
    });
})(jQuery);
```

That will run whatever code is inside the enclosure with jQuery passed in as the $ parameter and solved your problem.

Alternatively, if you're not adding any more code, just change the $ to jQuery like this...

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#nimble_portfolio_grid_1').addClass('importantRule');  
});
```

Finally, the best thing to do would be to use CSS correctly and just specify the element by ID...

```
<style>
    #nimble_portfolio_grid_1 { height: 5320px !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: very nice thing, i didnot know this. thanks a lot. now no errors any more, but it is not setting height, any idea? :(

Comment: If you can, just change the css to what I've put in the answer.